# Notation: setting multiple variables to zero

Tags: notation

I would like to set multiple variables to zero in an latex algorithm environment. Is there a more pleasing way than to state simply

$a=b=c=d=e=f=0$ ?

This looks cluttered. Maybe someone with more knowledge in math notation knows a better (shorter) way to express this. Thanks!

Comment: Actually indexing does not work here, because they are fundamentally different variables.

Comment: Because they express different things. Basically I am trying to explain a Matlab algorithm in pseudocode, that involves to initalize a bunch of variables in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an index set $I$ such that $I = \{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$, then you can simply say

$$\forall i \in I, i = 0$$

Comment: This looks nice. Is writing {a,b,c,d,e,f} = 0 also valid, or does this violate math notation rules?

Comment: This would mean that the set {a, b, c, d, e, f} is equal to the element 0, which is nonsensical. It's like saying "giraffe = kilogram", these are profoundly different entities.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have general some trouble expressing program code in math notation.